# Azure Databricks deployment- unable to create Private Subnet CIDR Range

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-virtual-network, vnet

In Azure, I have a virtual network (`vNET`) with following settings:

```
 Address space: 10.200.0.0/20
 subnet: 10.200.0.0/24
```

Inside the above vNET, I am trying to deploy an `Azure Databricks` with the following `Network` settings:

```
Public Subnet CIDR Range: 10.200.15.0/20
Private Subnet CIDR Range: 10.200.15.1/24
```

But on the `Private Subnet CIDR Range` above I get the following error:

> Public and private subnet ranges must be valid and non-conflicting

**Question**: What I may be doing wrong, and how can I resolve the above error?

**Remarks**:

- I have tried various variations of `10.200.15.1/24`(e.g. 10.200.15.0/24, 10.200.15.255/24 etc.) but I keep getting the same error. I am sure there must be a correct `Private Subnet CIDR Range` that I am not using.
- I noticed people have pointed out to some online tool such as the following, but I am not a  networking expert, and I am not sure how exactly I can use these tools to get correct Private Subnet CIDR Range. [CIRD Calculator](https://www.subnet-calculator.com/cidr.php), [Subnet Calculator for IPV4](https://www.site24x7.com/tools/ipv4-subnetcalculator.html), and [IP Calculator](https://www.colocationamerica.com/ip-calculator#quickhits).

**UPDATE** I'm following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/scenarios/quickstart-create-databricks-workspace-vnet-injection) from Azure team. When I tried the following settings, I get the error shown below:

> Subnet range is not within the Virtual Network range
> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CIDR tool I like to use is https://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr.

Your public subnet 10.200.15.0/20 has a starting IP of 10.200.0.0 and ends with 10.200.15.255.

Your private subnet 10.200.15.1/24 is not even valid. You can check [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52232241/how-to-validate-an-invalid-cidr-block) as to why that is.

Change the private subnet to 10.200.14.0/24. Keep the public subnet as is.
These are not overlapping and completely valid. 10.200.16.0/24 is outside the ip range of your vnet, so you can't use that.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Now I'm getting the error shown in **UPDATE** section that I just added to my post above. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is because your address space ends wt 10.200.15.255. Change the private subnet to 10.200.14.0/24.Keep the public subnet as is

Comment: your suggestion in your comment works. You may want to edit your post accordingly - and I will mark that as an `answer` so other readers can benefit from it, as well. Thank you.

Comment: Done the needful

Comment: I think you probably meant what you have in your comment: `Change the private subnet to 10.200.14.0/24. Keep the public subnet as is`. You may want to edit your post again. What you have in your comment worked for me.

Comment: Done that now..

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to create Azure Databricks Workspace with existing Vnet:**

I have created **Azure Databricks** workspace with existing **Virtual Network**.

> In your deployment you have mentioned public subnet **CIDR range: 10.200.15.0/20** is in same **Vnet Adress space range: 10.200.0.0/20**, so there is a possibility of conflict the network.

To resolve the issue, create different subnet range for both **Public** and **Private CIDR**, while you are creating the **Azure Databricks** workspace.

I created a **virtual network**, like below.

1. **Go to [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/) > Networking > Virtual Network.**

[image]

2. Under **IP** address section, add the below **IP** configuration details.

[image]

5. Once Vnet deployment is complete, navigate to **Virtual Network** and select **Address Space** under settings option, add additional address space range, like below.

[image]

Created **Azure Databricks** workspace. like below.

1. **Go** to [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/) **Analytics > Databricks**.

[image]

2. Once **Azure Databricks** deployment is completed, check the **Virtual Network** assocaited with **Databricks**.

[image]

4. Once the cluster is deployment is completed, navigate to **managed resource group** in **Azure Databricks** and check the resources.

[image]

Check the **Azure Databricks IP** address range, like below.

Go to **Azure Databricks workspace** > Select your **Cluster** > Select **Spark UI** > **Executors**

[image]

Refer the [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/scenarios/quickstart-create-databricks-workspace-vnet-injection) more about **Azure Databricks workspace**